# Websocket connection failed when depoly Bokeh server on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, bokeh

I got some troubles on deploying Bokeh server on AWS EC2.
I am using Apache 2.4 and Windows server 2019 on my EC2 instance, and I used Bokeh build-in Tornado http-server to run bokeh successfully in localhost:5006 on ec2.
[run well on localhost of EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9egG5.png)

The application source code is shown as following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Select,  Div

ticker1 = Select(title="test_ID：",value = "choose test_ID：", options = ["test001"], width=250)
welcome_div = Div(text='<b>Hello World</b>',width=1000, height=20, style={'font-size': '150%'})

layout = column(ticker1,welcome_div)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "test"
```

And I ran it with command:

```
 bokeh serve --show .\test1.py --allow-websocket-origin="*"
```

Then I use Apache as to proxy the localhost:5006 to port80, httpd-vhosts.conf is as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    CustomLog "C:/DeployTest/access_log" combined2
    ErrorLog "C:/DeployTest/error_log"
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /test1/ws ws://localhost:5006/test1
    ProxyPassReverse /test1/ws ws://localhost:5006/test1

    ProxyPass /test1 http://localhost:5006/test1/
    ProxyPassReverse /test1 http://localhost:5006/test1/

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    Alias "/static" "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/sitepackages/bokeh/server/static"
    <Directory "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/sitepackages/bokeh/server/static">
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in httpd.conf, I also have loaded all necessary module which are as following

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

However, when I tried to access from another computer by chrome, I get blank page except the title, which indicated that http connection may worked well, but websocket did not. I also checked chrome console and I get error which may prove my thinking:
[websocket connection failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlBfU.png)

Finally, I also checked the access log of Apache:

```
x.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [23/Jun/2021:10:24:28 +0900] "GET /test1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3779 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "TdW2sVmIwd3dfjU"
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [23/Jun/2021:10:24:29 +0900] "GET /test1/ws HTTP/1.1" 200 3803 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "TdW2sVmIwd3dfjU"
```

Any comment and help would be appreciated.

Comment: ProxyPass /test1 http://localhost:5006/test1/
    ProxyPassReverse /test1 http://localhost:5006/test1/   not sure if this is required why was this added ?

Comment: I assume it would be http proxy since I want to use both http and websocket in my app.

Comment: I don't think it works that way Apache2 is already  serving on port 80 so please comment or remove that lines and restart apache

Comment: Thanks for keeping following. I tried as you said, but I got a 404 error instead. Here, can I have another question for you: do i need to do some specific config in API Gateway to make websocket work on aws ec2?

Comment: By the way, for the Apache config, I referred  [Bokeh official docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#deployment-scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

I see that this issue is several years old, but I've been running up against the same problem recently. In your .py file, try including

```
from bokeh.settings import settings
settings.resources = 'inline'
```

and rather than the curdoc() command, try

```
pn.panel(layout).servable(title='Holoviews App')
```

to display the plot. I had a similar blank page issue on bokeh serve / nginx / Ubuntu EC2 until I made these changes.